# В какой директории нужно хранить Java-манифест?

Tags: java, maven

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>example.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>OTCJA</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.EntryPoint</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Когда я компилирую, собираю JAR-файл с помощью maven-package и пытаюсь его запустить, мне выдаёт сообщение о том, что не указан главный класс в манифесте (в точности сообщение показывать не буду, потому что оно не на русском и не на английском). Вообще говоря, манифеста у меня и нет, а в тех статьях, что я читал, априори подразумевается, что я знаю, в какую директорию надо класть манифест. Куда мне следует добавить манифест и нужно ли принимать какие-то меры, чтобы maven его увидел?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше всего настроить Maven так, чтобы он сам генерировал манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  ...

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>
                ${project.build.directory}/libs
              </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>
                com.example.App
              </mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

А для exec-плагина можно главный класс указать аргументом

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.App"
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Хотел бы только уточнить, за что отвечает каждый плагин. У меня уже были указаны `maven-compiler-plugin` для изменения версии Java по умолчанию и сборщик Jar-файла `exec-maven-plugin` для изменения класса по умолчанию. Вы добавили `maven-dependency-plugin`, который, судя по названию, создаёт что-то вроде карты зависимостей и `maven-jar-plugin`, который, видимо, будет теперь вместо `exec-maven-plugin`...

Comment: Важный момент: оба этих плагина в любом случае используются maven'ом. Упоминание их в конфигурации нужно только для того, чтобы изменить их поведение. Настройка maven-dependency-plugin копирует jar-файлы зависимостей в каталог target/libs в процессе упаковки приложения, чтобы вы могли легко перенести приложение в рабочее окружение. Настройка maven-jar-plugin позволяет указать параметры генерации манифеста. В данном случае имя главного класса и список его зависимостей.

Comment: всё понял. Единственный момент - хотел бы избежать использования консоли (я сам запускаю maven из ide). Может, следует оставить `exec-maven-plugin` вместе `maven-jar-plugin`?

Comment: Можно вместе. А можно оставить только exec-maven-plugin. Делайте так, как вам удобнее.

Comment: Хорошо, ещё раз спасибо 
Вам за объяснения!